# Java7 applet fails to load on Mountain lion & Lion

Tags: osx-server

I have developed sample cocoa (64 bit) webview application with all plug In settings enabled (setJavaEnabled:YES setPlugInsEnable:YES). But the Java applet plugin has been failed to load. I am using latest Java 7 from Oracle (update 25). I dont know the reason why plugin is fails in my sample always. Every thing works fine with **Safari and Firefox**.

The issue I am facing with both Lion and Mountain Lion (10.7.5 and 10.8.4)

Note: Test java applet url (http://www.java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp) to check the Java version  also fails in my sample application.

Any help would be appreciated.